# How To Fix CSS Border Radius From Cutting Off Border Corners

Tags: css

As You can see in this image I applied the border-radius property to a div and now it cuts off the corners on the border property. What's the best way to fix this?

[image: screenshot]

```
.store1,.store2,.store3,.store4,.store5 {
width: 160px;
padding: 5px;
margin: 5px 0 10px 0;
border: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
height: 70px;
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
background: #FFFFFF;
display: inline-block;
font-style: none;   
color: #000000;
font-style: normal;
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: and where are the those borders? a background-image? 
can you post the html?

Comment: The html is basic, it's just the <address> tag holding the address info.

Comment: ok, but I dont understand where are the blue bars. wich browser are you using?

Comment: I don't understand the question at all. You are aware of what border-radius does?

Comment: its not `border-radius` that's causing your problem.. might be something else.. provide more info on your issue..

Comment: As you can see in the image above, the edges of the line on the bottom of the boxes is cut off. I would like the line edges to be round.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the top, left, and right borders to 0 instead of just setting it the same color as your background. Then, your bottom border will run all the way to the edge.

[Example JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/xpNkC/)

Comment: I could not figure out why the hell and your explanation was like AHA! moment ty ty very much